# How can i group items of an array based on an condition without returning a key?

Tags: java, kotlin

I currently need to filter phone numbers of contacts by removing numbers if they are identical for called ID purposes.

For example :-> 
In an array like this *["+91 12345678","12345678","+91 123 456 78","99999999"]*

*"+91 12345678"* will be the same as *"12345678"* which will be the same as *"+91 123 456 78"*.

So the output here should be *["+91 12345678","99999999"]*

I tried going through various `group/groupby`  methods that kotlin provides for grouping elements but all of them require a key. Currently there is no particular key that groups all phone numbers.  I can obviously create multiple loops and solve this problem but i wanted to see if there is a much cleaner approach to this.

Comment: Create a NormalizedPhoneNumber class, which wraps a phone number string and normalizes it (i.e. removes the +91 prefix and all the spaces), and implements equals() and hashCode() based on the normalized result. Then transform all the phone numbers into instances of NormalizedPhoneNumber and store them in a HashSet<NormalizedPhoneNumber>. There you go: the hashset has eliminated all duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [distinctBy](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/distinct-by.html):

```
val list = listOf("+91 12345678","12345678","+91 123 456 78","99999999")
val output = list.distinctBy {
    it.replace(" ", "") // Remove whitespace
    // TODO also add the +91 prefix if it is not already there
}
```